# How to implement saml in jax-rs using Spring saml

Tags: jax-rs, keycloak, saml, saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to implement Spring saml in jax-rs. Is it possible to use spring saml in non spring application(jax-rs). I am doing this using AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer class by passing SecurityConfiguration.class to it. I am getting this message in my console. I am not able to redirect it to the Identity provider.

[http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl - No IDP specified, using default http://www.okta.com/exka6ervpp4VHG9Gq5d6
19:14:48.273 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: http://www.okta.com/exka6ervpp4VHG9Gq5d6
19:14:48.273 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of http://www.okta.com/exka6ervpp4VHG9Gq5d6
19:14:48.273 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: http://www.okta.com/exka6ervpp4VHG9Gq5d6
19:14:48.273 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of http://www.okta.com/exka6ervpp4VHG9Gq5d6
19:14:48.273 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of http://www.okta.com/exka6ervpp4VHG9Gq5d6
19:14:48.274 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint - Using discovery URL from extended metadata
19:14:48.274 [

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using SAML? It's much easier to use OIDC with Okta. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/12/30/java-jersey-jaxrs

Comment: Yes, it is a client requirement.